# Hypothesis testing: test involving proportion

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am comparing two diff treatments:

```
H0: p_t1 = p_t2
Ha: p_t1 ≠ p_t2
```

Treatment 1: 47030 trials, 5390 worked
Treatment 2: 340 trials, 11 worked

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
trials = np.array([[47030, 5390], [340, 11]])
stats.chi2_contingency(trials)
```

p-value from above is close to zero so null hyp is rejected. What changes I need to do in my approach to say one treatment is better than other? here I have only tested that they aren't equally effective.....any leads?

Comment: Well, check what the actual proportions are, if your treatment has a higher proportion of successes and you tested that these two proportions are not equal, then... that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you made a mistake there:

> Treatment 1: 47030 trials, 5390 worked

That means that `47030 - 5390 = 41640` did not work. For the contingency table, you need the number of "worked" and the number of "did not work", not the number of trials.

The same is true for `[340, 11]` which should be `[329, 11]`.

It will not change the $p$-value a lot in this case, but still.

Once statistical significance is established you can just compare `5390/47030` with `11/340` to see, which one was larger in the sample. The statistical significance then allows you to generalize from the sample to the population.